# Comparing column to specific value, returns the value of other column to another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

the title might be confusing so here's the scenario:

I want the Column C (New) to get the value of Column A (Owner) if Column B (Status) is Inactive. But I want it print on row by row, for example, since Column B row 3 is "Inactive", I want to get owner2 to print in column C row 2, and also since Column B row 6 is "Inactive" I want to get owner5 to print in column C row 3,

Here is my formula:
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, MATCH("Inactive",B:B, 0)), "")

I have this formula printed on each row in column C, but this doesnt do what I intended to do, because if Column B row 3 is Inactive, this formula displays owner2 value in multiple rows in column C.

I hope I can get answer without using Excel-VB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put in C2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(B$1:B$6="Inactive",ROW($1:$6)),ROW()-1)),"")
```

> This is an Array formula and must be conformed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

Then simply copy down from C2. Just use "Evaluate Formula" to see how it works. But if there are still any questions left, just ask.

**EDIT**

To stay with your non-array formula in a non-array way, just put in C3 (C2 will stay with your formula):

```
=IF(C2="","",IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C2,A:A,0)+1):A99999, MATCH("Inactive",INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0)+1):B99999, 0)), ""))
```

This is a non-array way, but has the restriction, that ALL "Owner" need to be unique. If one is there 2 times, it may fail. But if they are all unique, then this formula will be much faster for bigger tables ;)